# visual .net savefiledialog The dialog never appears

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem, and I spent so much time looking for the solution, but I haven't fine the answer. The problem is that I´m trying to use the "savefiledialog", when I run it in the localhost of my pc it works perfectly, the dialog appear with out any problem and I´m able to save the file as it suppose to work... But when I publish it in the iis server and I try to use it, it doesn't appear, I mean the dialog savefile doesn't appear, I put a Try Catch, but It doesn't send me any error message, I don't know where is the problem, I hope someone have a blue of what is happening. Thanks in advance,  my code is:

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Dim _newThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Descarga)
    _newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    _newThread.Start("C:\Compras\Prueba.txt")

End Sub
```

Private Sub Descarga(ByVal _ruta As Object)

```
    Dim Dialog As New System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog

    Dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    Dialog.Title = "Save text Files"
    Dialog.CheckFileExists = True
    Dialog.CheckPathExists = True
    Dialog.DefaultExt = "txt"
    Dialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    Dialog.FilterIndex = 2
    Dialog.RestoreDirectory = True

    If Dialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        FileCopy(_ruta, Dialog.FileName)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Q: What happens if you don't spawn a thread for the dialog?  Q: Did you step through the debugger to see if your thread is successfully created?  If it starts?

Comment: This is asp.net? You realize the dialog would have to open on the **server** right?

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, if I don't use the thread, it send me this error message: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE... I´m shure that the thread is successfully created I make a test and it doesn't have the problem, the problem is in this line: Dialog.ShowDialog() before that line everything works fine.

Comment: I expect it to show on the client side, is this possible?

Comment: Only if you send the file to the client as the response. Then the client can choose what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the windows forms SaveFileDialog. When you execute ShowDialog it will open it on the server, not in the client browser.

You'll need to send the file to the client as the response.

**Edit**
Something like this should prompt the client to save the file:

```
Dim FileName As String = "Prueba.txt"
Dim FilePath As String = "C:\Compras\"
Dim response As System.Web.HttpResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
response.ClearContent()
response.Clear()
response.ContentType = "text/plain"
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";")
response.TransmitFile(FilePath + FileName)
response.Flush()
response.End()
```

Comment: there is a way to it opens in the client browser? Or it is not possible? Thanks for your help Sani Huttunen and sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: Yes, but I need the window "save as", if I send it with response, it open the file in the browser :(